# InputScopeNameValue.PhraseList in a WP7 app

Tags: windows-phone-7, inputscope

Has anyone used InputScopeNameValue.PhraseList as an inputscope filter in a WP7 TextBox?

Let's say I have a list of tags and I want the TextBox SIP to autosuggest words that come from that set.  The InputScopeNameValue.PhraseList inputscope is supposed to provide that capability...

```
        taglist.InputScope = new InputScope() { Names = { new InputScopeName() { NameValue = InputScopeNameValue.PhraseList } } };
```

...but I can't find any ways to add the actual words to the InputScope.

BTW, this issue extends to any of the negative enumeration values - which all require additional values (e.g. InputScopeNameValue.RegularExpression).

The [code](http://www.wikiencyclopedia.net/net/DotNET/DotNET/8.0/untmp/WIN_WINDOWS/lh_tools_devdiv_wpf/Windows/wcp/Core/System/Windows/Input/InputScope.cs/1/InputScope.cs) for the WPF InputScope class seems to have properties like PhraseList and RegularExpression but I can't find those on the InputScope supplied in WP7.

Has anyone gotten this to work, and if so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

InputScope PhraseList isn't supported on the phone. I wanted to do exactly what you are trying to do, fir a Twitter input box. I was going to suggest @TwitterName's.

WP7 does not support app defined dictionaries or phrase lists as part of the keyboard auto suggest

Pat